# Exception in Hibernate program in eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate

In my hibernate programme I am getting the following exception:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use

My Hibernate.cfg.config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mayank</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="show-sql">true></property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<mapping class="one.Student"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

The Student file is 

package one;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Student
{
@Id
private Long id;

private int roll;
private String name;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getRoll() {
    return roll;
}
public void setRoll(int roll) {
    this.roll = roll;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Student(Long id, int roll, String name) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.roll = roll;
    this.name = name;
}
public Student() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
     }
```

What does the Exception mean and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-error-an-annotationconfiguration-instance-is-required-to-use/

Answer (score 0):

In place of Configuration `cfg = new Configuration();`
we need to use AnnotationConfiguration 
`cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();`

For XML File: Configuration
For Annotation: AnnotationConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

(1)Add the dependency in Maven's `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

(2)Use `AnnotationConfiguration` to build session factory
   Normal Hibernate XML file mapping is using `Configuration()`

```
return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

For Hibernate annotation, you have to change it to `AnnotationConfiguration`

```
return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I downloaded dtd file locally on my machine under path(`D:/Praful_WorkSpace/firstHibernate/src/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`) and then I mentioned that path in the xml file declaration. I followed same thing for both the xml files.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"file:///D:/Praful_WorkSpace/firstHibernate/src/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```